# difference between URL rewriting and URL routing mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am trying to learn MVC and need  help in understanding the difference between URL rewriting and URL routing in MVC.

Answer (score 1):

URL Routing is the routing done by MVC which is , When we type something in the url space, then it will first invoke the

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

which is in Global.asax.cs `Application_Start()` method if you put a break point in that then you could understand the routing method , then it will call the

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Which is in App_start=>RouteConfig class you can find out the RegisterRoutes method here . Here we can define the structure of our url and here it will decide which controller and action should be invoked.
This process is url Routing

URL rewriting is entire diff concept 
Let us assume our controller name is **Customer** and action name is **Login** 
when we run the application our url will be like the below
http://Localhost:233/Customer/Login 
but the client ended http://Localhost:233/Login  only, for SEO purposes 
In order to achieve this we have to rewrite the url by keeping the same controller and action name 
to know more about url rewriting i have explained attribute rewriting in http://grandhah.blogspot.in/2015/07/url-rewriting-in-mvc-4-attribute-routing.html Please visit and let me know you are clarified enough.. good day